# Unable to run Spring Boot simple REST service

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to run a basic Spring Boot application created with the Spring Initializr. I see the application is pretty much the same of many examples available on the Web but I get a '404' page not found:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
@RestController
public class Controller {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String hello() {
                return "it works!";

        }
}
```

This is the main class:

```
package com.example.springtest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }
}
```

The pom.xml includes just the web starter:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>demo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <properties>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>


</project>
```

The execution:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080

{"timestamp":"2018-12-11T09:18:59.236+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/"}
```

Do I miss any starter to get it working?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `@ComponentScan()` annotation in the main method class and pass the path to the rest service component scan as a parameter.

because by default it only include the service which is in the package and sub package of the main class . so for adding other path service you have to pass the path in component scan annotation.

Comment: I agree, you are missing the Component Scan because the main class is in a deeper package than the Controller, This would work if it is the other way around.

Comment: Yes. main class is in  package com.example.springtest;

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know this subtle difference!